# What is the best POS service that also offers REST APIs

Tags: api, pos

I am in a search for open source POSes, I would love if I get such service for free or atleast a trial, The main goal is to have such POS that can provide an API too against it services or something of sort where we can build our own REST services to automate the task and all that.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is the most popular Point of Sale API. it has legendary documentation and has SDKs for javascript (ES6), Ruby, Python, PHP, Java, Node, Go, and .Net. Stripe has no monthly fees, however they do take a 1.4% + 20p for European cards, and 2.9% + 20 for all non-European cards if your account is registered in the UK.

https://stripe.com/gb?utm_campaign=paid_brand-UK_en_Search_Brand_Stripe-2032860449&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&ad_content=355351450265&utm_term=kwd-94834400&utm_matchtype=e&utm_adposition=&utm_device=c

Failing that Square's payment API is also incredibly popular.It uses a similar pricing model to Stripe

https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payments-pricing